# Basic auth Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Как организовать простую авторизацию на AngularJs?  Я гуглил, но ничего подходящего не нашел.  Поделитесь скринкастами/статьями.  Спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, авторизация происходит на сервере. Как вы видите авторизацию на `angular`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать именно **[basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)** , то для начала вам будет удобнее работать с библиотекой для кодирования в base64. Например [этой](https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64).

После подключения этой библиотеки, вам нужно будет добавить в конфиге http header

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['base64'])
    .config(function($httpProvider, $base64) {
        var auth = $base64.encode("foo:bar");
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + auth;
    })
```

Более подробно можете почитать в [статье](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx).